# A linux shell that tracks time on the CPU and memory usage

Tags: c, linux, shell, memory-management, cpu-usage

A short synopsis of what I'm trying to do:

Emulate a shell program that executes commands as the user enters them in its own process, and after each process finished, output the total time that all child processes and the shell have spent on the CPU, and the max amount of memory that a single process has used.

Creating the shell and executing the commands isn't a problem, but when it comes to keeping track of the statistics about the processes is what has me stuck.

For keeping track of the CPU time, I was going to use the time system call and pass the user's command through the shell and into time so the process could finish running and at the end of execution I would have the information from time available to me. But when it comes to getting the time that the shell (current program) has spent on the CPU, I'm not entirely sure what to do because every implementation of time that I've seen or come across uses the above method of passing the commands and arguments into time, and I can't do that with the shell. The only idea I ahve at the moment is to make the shell a child process as well, run that through time, and when the shell finishes running a child process, reboot the shell, pull the information from time, and reboot the shell. Which seems very round about, but I can't find any system calls to do what I want.

As for the memory usage, I was thinking about using top and then pulling the information out, but iirc top only monitors current memory usage, not total. The only other thing I could think of would be going into /proc// and trying to pull the information out from somewhere in there. Which again, seems very roundabout.

Any nudge in the right direction would be awesome. All of this is done in C, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the source of `top` to find out how it does the tracking?

Comment: `strace -c` and `ltrace -c` should give you a good idea

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to run every user command as a separate process and when process finishes grab the resources usage information. Ok, running command as process is easy enough (see fork() and exec* family). What about resource usage (time, memory, etc)? I suggest take a look at getrusage() syscall.

man says:

> The  getrusage()  function shall
>   provide measures of the resources used
>   by the
>          current process or its terminated and waited-for child
>   processes. If the value of
>          the who argument is RUSAGE_SELF, information  shall  be 
>   returned  about
>          resources  used  by  the  current process. If the value of the
>   who argument is
>          RUSAGE_CHILDREN, information shall be returned about resources used
>   by the 
>          terminated and waited-for children of the current  process.

Lets see what information this syscall provides:

```
struct rusage {
    struct timeval ru_utime; /* user time used */
    struct timeval ru_stime; /* system time used */
    long   ru_maxrss;        /* maximum resident set size */
    long   ru_ixrss;         /* integral shared memory size */
    long   ru_idrss;         /* integral unshared data size */
    long   ru_isrss;         /* integral unshared stack size */
    long   ru_minflt;        /* page reclaims */
    long   ru_majflt;        /* page faults */
    long   ru_nswap;         /* swaps */
    long   ru_inblock;       /* block input operations */
    long   ru_oublock;       /* block output operations */
    long   ru_msgsnd;        /* messages sent */
    long   ru_msgrcv;        /* messages received */
    long   ru_nsignals;      /* signals received */
    long   ru_nvcsw;         /* voluntary context switches */
    long   ru_nivcsw;        /* involuntary context switches */
};
```

I think this would be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: This helped a lot, but I'm still a little stuck. I've checked the documentation, and I can't figure out how to extract information from ru_utime. All the documentation I've found says that sys/time.h defines the timeval struct, but even after importing it I can't declare a structure of that type or access the members that it's supposed to have.

Comment: Hm... you should include <time.h> header. It includes bits/time.h wich defines timeval structure. This structure has tv_sec filed which stores the seconds and tv_usec which stores microseconds. You can use tv_sec with gmtime go get tm structure that converts seconds to years, months, days, etc.